# Lightning table header and body are not aligning

Tags: lightning-aura-components, datatable

[image]I have a component where the data is displayed using html data table aura:iteration. However the header is not aligned with the body. I have tried with many slds css but no success. Can anyone pls help with this issue?

```
      <table class="slds-table slds-table_fixed-layout slds-table_striped">
            <thead>
                <lightning:recordEditForm aura:id="recordEditForm" 
                                          recordTypeId="{!recData.RecordTypeId}"
                                          objectApiName="mstns__c">
                    <tr class="slds-text-title_caps">
                        <th scope="col" id="Select">
                            <div class="slds-truncate" title="Select">Select</div>
                        </th>
                        <th scope="col">
                            <div class="slds-truncate" title=" Name">Milestone Name</div>
                        </th>
                        <th scope="col">
                            <div class="slds-truncate" title="Status">Status</div>
                        </th>

                    </tr></lightning:recordEditForm>
            </thead>               
            <tbody>
                <lightning:accordion aura:id="accordion" activeSectionName="Milestone Records">
                    <aura:iteration items="{!v.dataRows}" var="recData">
                        <lightning:recordEditForm aura:id="recordEditForm" 
                                                  recordTypeId="{!recData.RecordTypeId}"
                                                  objectApiName="mstns__c">
                            <tr>
                                <aura:if isTrue="{!v.objectRec == 'Opportunity'}">
                                    <td scope="row" data-label="Select">
                                        <!-- Checked for all new Milestones -->
                                        <ui:inputCheckbox aura:id="milestoneSelected" value="true"/>
                                    </td>
                                    <aura:set attribute="else">                                
                                        <th scope="row" data-label="Select">
                                            <!-- Checked for existing Milestones and greyed for completed Milestones-->   
                                            <aura:if isTrue="{!if(not(empty(recData.Id)), true,false) }">       

                                                <ui:inputCheckbox aura:id="milestoneSelected_mp" value="true" disabled="{!and(recData.Status__c=='Completed',recData.Close_Date__c!=null)}"/>
                                                <aura:set attribute="else">
                                                    <ui:inputCheckbox aura:id="milestoneSelected_mp" value="false" disabled="{!and(recData.Status__c=='Completed',recData.Close_Date__c!=null)}"/>
                                                </aura:set>
                                            </aura:if>
                                        </th></aura:set></aura:if>
                                <td scope="row" data-label="Milestone Name">
                                    <lightning:formattedText value="{!recData.Milestone_Name__c}" required="false"/>
                                </td>
                                <td data-label="Status">

                                    <lightning:inputField fieldName="Status__c" value="{!recData.Status__c}" disabled="{!and(recData.Status__c=='Completed',recData.Close_Date__c!=null)}" class="cellUp"/>       </td>  

                            </tr>
                        </lightning:recordEditForm>

                    </aura:iteration>   </lightning:accordion>
                <lightning:button variant="brand" label="Submit" title="Submit the records" onclick="{!c.clickSubmit}" />
                <!--<lightning:button variant="Neutral" label="Previous" title="Go to previous screen" onclick="{!c.clickPrevious}" />-->
                <lightning:button variant="Neutral" label="Cancel" title="Cancel" onclick="{!c.Cancel}" />
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the lightning:recordEditForm and lightning:accordion elements from your code. They are not compatible with tables. If you need a collapsible table, consider using lightning:treeGrid instead. To save/load data, you can use force:recordData or an Apex Controller.

Comment: I need lightning:recordEditForm for showing up the table as a form, giving the ability to the user to edit values. I am fetching/creating the data using an apex controller and passing the data to the table. 
This lightning:accordion was just a try. I can remove this. @sfdcfox

Comment: @Kanikala Again, that's not how the lightning:recordEditForm works; it's used to look just like a normal record edit form in the UI. You're not even using the form correctly; it is meant to be used with lightning:inputField. As written, you're not doing yourself any favors.